# PayPal API with Laravel

Tags: php, api, laravel, plugins, paypal

I am using a paypal plugin, and and for some reason I can't get paypal to go to my callback url when payment is complete. I have used the same plugin before which worked so it must be something stupid I am doing.

Here's a sample array of the data I am passing into the plugin

Array

```
(
    [sandboxMode] => 1
    [successUrl] => http://x.x.x.x/safespacesforkids/rebuild/public/payment/success
    [cancelUrl] => http://x.x.x.x/safespacesforkids/rebuild/public/assessment/checkout
    [backendUrl] => http://x.x.x.x/safespacesforkids/rebuild/public/payment/pp/316e7c50a117c91b392a013a6e1a22e9a4f97b1e
    [merchantAccount] => myemail@domain.com
    [language] => EN
    [currency] => AUD
    [invoice] => 55ca0738e638d
    [purpose] => Company Name
    [amount] => 180.68
    [remark] => 
)
```

When I copy `backendUrl` in to my browser and go there myself it processes the order just fine. but paypal won't

My code

```
public function redirect()
{
    //My Basket - Info
    $basket = Cart::getBasket();

    //Make payment hash
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    $user->hash = sha1(rand().time());
    $user->save();

    $paypalInfo = array(
        'sandboxMode'     => true,
        'successUrl'      => URL::route('payment.success'),
        'cancelUrl'       => URL::route('assessment.checkout'),
        'backendUrl'      => URL::route('payment.paypal', $user->hash),
        'merchantAccount' => System::first()->paypal_email,
        'language'        => 'EN',
        'currency'        => 'AUD',
        'invoice'         => uniqid(),
        'purpose'         => 'Safe Spaces for Kids',
        'amount'          => Helper::price($basket['total']),
        'remark'          => ''
    );

    Helper::pr($paypalInfo,1);

    $adapter = Gateway::driver('Paypal')->initialize($paypalInfo);
    $generated = $adapter->render();

    return View::make('payment/redirect', ['form' => $generated]);
}
```